# Borrowing books a library data structure

Tags: data-structures, computer-science, software-design

First off, I would like to mention the question is a homework question.
I have been pondering about the implementation for long enough.

I have to think and implement a library software that has the following functionalities:

1. add/remove a new subscriber.
2. borrow/return a book.
3. what books the following subscriber have?
4. which subscriber holds the following book?
5. list of the subscribers with most books.

I thought of implementing a heap and 2 red black trees, the problem is that the space complexity is high. So I was wondering if I am missing something.

The subscribers are stored by I.Ds, the books have code names.
One Red Black tree is for the subscribers and the other is for the borrowed books.
The heap is a max heap, in order to implement the last requirement.

**I cannot use anything else but data structures.**

Thanks for **any** insights and answers.

Comment: Can you expand? Your R-B-trees are one for subscriber and one for books? Maybe hash tables are worth consideration here. Also, a heap just for req 5 seems like overkill, it should be possible to track that in O(1) time overhead per borrow/return operation with a doubly linked list of doubly linked lists. But that will possibly mean your person object needs knowledge of the DLLs, which is not nice from a design point of view.

Comment: Well, you are right one rb is for the subscribers and one for the books that are borrowed. And it is an overkill just for that but I need to return the list of subscribers O(n) would be nice but it cannot be O(n) like this. I tought about combining the data structures together and do a sort of EAV modeling pattern with a hash table, searches will take longer(possibly O(n). and there may be collisions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can also use containers, like structs? Use:

- One hash set/hash table for the books:
  Additionally store a flag which determines whether the book is borrowed and the subscriber it's borrowed to.
- One hash map from subscriber->linked list of books, to store not only all the subscribers but also which books they have borrowed.

This allows you to perform all listed tasks in O(1), except sorting the subscribers by the count of the books they have borrowed.

Comment: I actually have to use only primitive data stuctures(ones that I have learnt in the course) so I am pretty limited, else I would have used a treap and than I could have had the ID's in the bst and the number of currently borrowed books as a heap.

Comment: @Shlomi Can you list those primitive data structures?

Comment: @Dave I can use BST, RB Tree, Hashtables, Linked Lists(double and single), stacks, queues and min/max heaps. I can extend other data structures but then I will need to prove their correctness(and their properties).

Comment: By the way I maybe I didn't mention but I have to implement those structures(meaning I cannot use any library or already native).

Comment: Since you must implement them (programmatically), you can also define structs to store additional information with your entities. A hash map is nothing else than a hash set/table with pairs as elements. Do you have to fulfill any time complexity bounds? If not I would just program a sort for the last requirement - shouldn't hurt anybody.

Comment: Well the problem with hash tables is that they will have inefficient space complexity(O(n^2) or even more) but the time complexity will decrease to O(1). If I use a hash table for the subscribers than it's either I open up an array of 10^9 members(direct addressing, no collisions), or I use open addressing with a hash function. On the other hand if I use RB Trees the complexities will be even O(n) space and O(logn) time(most of the time) and O(nlogn) for the last req, maybe I could just use counting sort for that and than I will reduce the time to O(n + k)

Comment: A hash table has O(n) space complexity. The problem with the tree is that you have to store the book count as keys? How are you going to find the customer that belongs to the maximum entry? How are you going to update the weights in the tree when someone borrows/returns a book. In the worst case you'll have to traverse the complete tree to find someone because everybody has the same number of books.

Comment: No, I wanted to add another field to the subscriber node with book count and a linked lists of books for each subscriber node.